# большие иконки в ubuntu 20.04 при переключение раскладки клавиатуры

Tags: linux

Как настроить ubuntu 20.04, чтобы поверх всех окон отображались иконки переключения раскладки клавиатуры. Как показано на картинке в ссылке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Здравствуйте, при смене языковой раскладки клавиатуры с русской на украинскую, должна появляться в центре экрана иконка (окно), на которой показано, что активная языковая раскладка клавиатуры стала украинская (показано это оранжевым цветом). Сейчас у меня при переключении раскладки вообще никаких иконок (окна) в центре экрана не появляется. И я не всегда понимаю на какую языковую расскладку клавиатуры я переключился.  Возможно  , что в центре кнана смена языка будет отображаться  визуально по другому, но главное чтобы это было и работало. Визуально это показано на изображении в вопросе.